# Rails MiniTest, Why doesn't this process as a success instead of an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, assertraises

```
[woo:~/Development … e-roles/test] master(+7/-3) 23s ± rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 18905
Run options: --seed 34925

# Running:

E

Error:
UserTest#test_User_must_have_an_email_address:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2019-05-16 23:08:53.696224', '2019-05-16 23:08:53.696224', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:4



Finished in 0.019202s, 52.0779 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Now, here is the user_test.rb

```
[woo:~/Development … e-roles/test] master(+7/-3) 1 ± cat models/user_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "User must have an email address" do
     user = User.new
     assert_raise SQLite3::ConstraintException   do
     user.save
     end
    end
end
```

I thought this would process as a success since I'm asserting that it is to raise a SQLite3::ConstraintException, which it does.  I want to have the test succeed if the proper exception is raised.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to get this test to pass, you'll want to assert about the Ruby exception, not the SQLite3 exception. Your ActiveRecord model (I'm guessing) is where the constraint is defined.

Something like this:

```rb
assert_raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique do
  user.save
end
```

Asserting about the Ruby exception will make this test pass even if you switch to a different database in the future, which is one of the main reasons to use an ORM.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying and the message does have that string in it.  Unfortunately, that does not change anything.  The user model contains:
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable That does not give me a hint about the record being unique unless rememberable implies that.  Where does it require an email?  How do I enforce that and require that AND test for it?

Comment: I think the question I understood, and the thing you're trying to figure out, don't match up. Based on what you've described, the validation comes from Devise. That library can change how your application works, and what it requires (like email), in magical ways. Once you figure it out, I'd suggest adding your own email constraint, or scrapping this test-- in that case it would be testing Devise's code. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: So, you're saying add a constraint in the user model that the email must be present to be saved and then test that?

Comment: Start by figuring out why emails must be unique. That constraint was either added by a migration in the app (you'd see it in `db/migrate/`) or by Devise. It sounds like it's Devise, but I haven't seen the user model. Several Devise features deal with emails (confirmable, validatable) so that would make sense. Then a validation on the user model would make sense. I'd want my app to be able to catch bad data by itself.